# Hover doesn't work but click does

Tags: jquery, click, hover

Update: Broken on Chrome only, Safari seems to work fine. Maybe it's something in my star.

I have HTML that looks like this

```
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
```

I want to trigger an event on hover. So i have code that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.star').each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
      console.log('hover');
    });
  });
});
```

I even tried this:

```
 $(".star").hover(function(){ 
    console.log("hover triggered"); 
  });
```

I have tried multiple variations of this code with no success. THe hover code only works when I **click** on star, but not when I hover. Please help as I'm really lost as to why this isn't working. When I try this on JS Fiddle, it works, but my page isn't set up that much differently. WHy would it work on click but not on hover, when then trigger is hover?

Comment: you don't need the .each loop to bind.. just do `$('.star').hover`

Comment: I tried all variables, including .on('hover')... yet the trigger happenes on click not hover, which is very frustrating

Comment: "When I try this on JS Fiddle, it works," Well then there must be other code that you haven't shared.

Comment: There isn't any other releavnt code. Just the star element

Comment: yes, i can do $(".star").hide() and it hides the stars, and $(".star").length and it counts them

Comment: How are you loading the jQuery library?  What happens if you add `alert("I am here");` just under `$(document).ready(` line ?

Comment: it works. when i do alert($), it shows jquery in the alerrt

Comment: Provide a link to your site if possible

Comment: UPdate: COde is chrome specfic, it works on safari, i'm investigating as to why that is

Comment: of course you have clear your cache, right?

Comment: yeah, not a cache thing

Comment: what about firefox? does it works?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. Turns out I had previously been using Chrome's Developer Tools to emulate a touch screen, which screwed with the hover event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.star').hover(function(){
        console.log('hover');
    });
});
```

Comment: tried this, it works when i click the ".star", but not when I hover over it. the stars have a width and height, and a border, and i can see the elemetn but when I hover over it, nothing happenes. only on click does the event gets triggered

Comment: hum, is this a plugin or something?